# How does linking a discussion to a proposal work exactly?

Tags: support, area-51

Forgive me if this is documented somewhere and I'm being blind, but how does linking between a discussion and a proposal work exactly?

The system seems to add

> Proposal: [Link to proposal](http://www.example.com)

style links. Is this the only style that works for a linking? What are the rules here?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, fair enough. According to what I see, *any* link to a proposal will do to link it.

Comment: Yup, nice example [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/272/translation-proposals-one-on-one-or-free-for-all) by the way :)